# Oracle: Week of

Tags: oracle11g

I have the below SQL Server syntax and I'm trying to transition the syntax into Oracle. I'm trying to capture the week of data, for example: 1/16-1/22

For example:

```
FullDate       Week of (PreferredFormat):
  1/1/2016          12/27-01/02
  1/2/2016          12/27-01/02 
  1/3/2016          01/03-01/09
```

Below is my SQL Server syntax:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, fulldate)-1), fulldate), 110) + '-' + 
 CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), DATEADD(dd, 7-    (DATEPART(dw, fulldate)), fulldate), 110) AS 'WeekOf'
-----------------------------------------------
 ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(05), DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, fulldate)-1), fulldate), 10) + '-' + 
 CONVERT(NVARCHAR(05), DATEADD(dd, 7- (DATEPART(dw, fulldate)), fulldate), 10) AS 'WeekOf_2'
-----------------------------------------------------
  ,REPLACE(replace(left(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(05), DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, fulldate)-1), fulldate), 10),5),'0',''),'-','/') + '-' +
  REPLACE(replace(left(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(05), DATEADD(dd, 7- (DATEPART(dw, fulldate)), fulldate), 10),5),'0',''),'-','/') AS 'WeekOf_3'
```

Comment: `to_char('iw', fulldate)`: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by "trying to capture the week of data"?

Comment: I have date: 1/1/2016 and I want to capture the beginning and end of the week. Like I have above for SQL Server. *Editing question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your weeks run from Sunday to Saturday. The solution below uses the `next_day()` function; please note that its use is dependent on the date language of your session (which is, unfortunately, not an optional parameter to the function). Also, as you migrate from another DB product, it would be much better if you put the dates in a column of datatype DATE; I assume the inputs are dates in `date` datatype, not `nvarchar`.

```
with
     inputs ( dt ) as (
       select to_date('1/1/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select to_date('1/2/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
       select to_date('1/3/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
     )
-- end of test data (not part of the solution!); SQL query begins below this line
select dt, 
       to_char(next_day(dt, 'Sunday') - 7, 'mm/dd-') || 
                        to_char(next_day(dt, 'Sunday') - 1, 'mm/dd') as week_of
from   inputs
;

DT         WEEK_OF
---------- -----------
01/01/2016 12/27-01/02
01/02/2016 12/27-01/02
01/03/2016 01/03-01/09

3 rows selected.
```